# HttpResponseRedirect в Django. Не могу настроить redirect на нужную страницу

Tags: django, redirect

После заполнения формы должна появится страница, где сказано, что форма успешно отправлена.
Но в моем коде выдает ошибку:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/candidate/done.html
Using the URLconf defined in ntkproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. done
2. 
3. grappelli/
4. admin/
The current path, candidate/done.html, didn't match any of these.
```

Не могу настроить редирект на страницу done.html

Вот **views.py**:

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import AnketaForm
from .models import Anketa

def anketa_create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnketaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('candidate/done.html')
    else:
        form = AnketaForm()
    return render(request, 'candidate/anketa_create.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py** (apps/candidate)

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.anketa_create_view, name = 'anketa_create_view'),
    ]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from candidate.views import anketa_create_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('done/', anketa_create_view),
    path('', anketa_create_view),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**done.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
    <h1 class="display-3">Спасибо за Ваш отклик!</h1>
    <p class="lead">
        Мы внимательно ознакомимся с Вашим резюме.
    </p>
</div>
<div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

из **urls.py** убрать `path('done/', anketa_create_view)`

в **views.py** `return HttpResponseRedirect('candidate/done.html')` изменить на `return render(request, 'candidate/done.html', {})`

Answer (score 1):

я думаю стоит перенести адрес `done` из `url` проекта в `url` приложения. Т.к. в редиректе вы переходите по адресс `url` имя_приложения/done а у вас такого url нет.

```
def done(request):
    return render(request, 'candidate/done.html', {})
```

**urls.py (apps/candidate)**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.anketa_create_view, name = 'anketa_create_view'),
    path('done', views.anketa_create_view, name = 'done'),
    ]
```

Comment: результат тот же, 404

Comment: @KirillRyzhov функцию для вывода этой страницы написали? добавил в ответ простейшую

Comment: 404, с прописанной функцией

Comment: @KirillRyzhov напишите так return HttpResponseRedirect('done')

Comment: 404. попробовал через HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('done')), теперь возвращает пустую форму

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае работает вариант: В **urls.py** назначить имя *path('done', views.anketa_create_view, name = '**done**')*

а в **views.py** импортировать *from django.shortcuts import render, **redirect*** и вернуть из функции *return redirect('**done**')*